# Play swf file in UIwebview in iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8, flash

Hello I have to play swf file in UIwebview. I did r&d on it. But didn't get the solution for it.I know ios does not support swf file.Also safari support it in mac not in iphone.Is there a single alternate way to play swf file in ios8? Its mandatory for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Flash is never supported on iOS devices , Steve jobs Decision

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Playing swf file is strictly prohibited in iOS. Still this one might help you,

[UIWebView html file with swf load external link, but internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893153/uiwebview-html-file-with-swf-load-external-link-but-internal)

Comment: ok, one more thing when i play it in mac with safari. It works but when same link i play in iphone with safari it doesn't. why?

Comment: because .swf files will never ever work on iPhone devices